# Como selecionar uma declaração switch/case a cada clique no botao

Tags: javascript, if, switch, else, case

Gostaria de fazer lista(gem) de `A-Z`.

Um detalhe, baseia-se em quebrar/dividir esta lista(gem) alfabeto em partes:

Embora a minha dificuldade esta em, após ser clicado no botão, o mesmo trazer a lista assim:

1º clique no botao - então a **primeira parte** seja carregado nesta ordem.

A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I

2ª clique no botao - logo é carregado a **segunda parte.**

J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
V

3ª clique no botao - então findará a **terceira parte** com o restante do alfabeto.

R
S
T
U
W
X
Y
Z

Cada vez que eu clicar no mesmo botão, quero adicionar +1 a variável.

Por exemplo: tenho uma variável `count` recebendo o valor `0` inicial, ao clicar neste botão o mesmo começa o `count++` para 1 e assim sucessivamente, executando cada bloco de declaração dentro do `stwich/case`.

Para maiores, detalhes observe a lógica abaixo:

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){

 var contador = 0;
 contador++;

 document.getElementById("conta").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=contador;


switch (contador){
 case "1":
 for ( i = 1; i < 9; i++ ){
 ler = String.fromCharCode(i+64);
 document.body.innerHTML += ler +"<br>";
 }
 break;
 case "2":
 for ( i = 1; i < 9; i++ ){
 ler = String.fromCharCode(i+64);
 document.body.innerHTML += ler +"<br>";
 }
 break;
 case "3":
 for ( i = 1; i < 8; i++ ){
 ler = String.fromCharCode(i+64);
 document.body.innerHTML += ler +"<br>";
 }
 break;
 alert("Ok! Fim de Listagem.\nRetome sua pesquisa.");
}
</script>
```

> No entanto, tenho enfrentado dificuldade em fazer esta seleção a cada clic no botão.
>
> Qualquer dica, sugestão e exemplos simplório e/ou prático, tudo para contribuir, será bem-vindo como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var c = 0
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function a() {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    switch (c.toString()) {
        case "1":
            for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                ler = String.fromCharCode(i + 64);
                result.innerHTML += ler + "<br>";
            }
            break;
        case "2":
            for (i = 9; i < 17; i++) {
                ler = String.fromCharCode(i + 64);
                result.innerHTML += ler + "<br>";
            };
            break;
        case "3":
            for (i = 17; i < 27; i++) {
                ler = String.fromCharCode(i + 64);
                result.innerHTML += ler + "<br>";
            }
            break;
    }
    if (c == 3) {
        c = 0;
    }
    alert("Ok! Fim de Listagem.\nRetome sua pesquisa.");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="a(c++);" value="click me">
<div id="result">
</div>
```